# jQuery selector to select ONLY specific 2 classes, excluding any other?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

There are lots of questions asking for selecting elements with 2 classes.
But I want to ask that what if I want the get elements that has only 2 provided classes and **excluding any other elements that have any other additional classes**? In other words, no elements with additional classes wanted.

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="a b">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="a b c">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

In my case, I want to get ONLY the second div element, NOT the one with `a b c` classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Second edit**: Using just css this selector will select both cases class 'a' in first place or in second place:

```
$('div[class="a b"],div[class="b a"]')
```

**Edit**: You need to filter the selection and exclude elements with a third class:

```
$('.a.b')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.classList[2] == null;
    });
```

---

```js
$('.a.b')
    .filter(function() {
    return this.classList[2] == null;
    })
    .addClass('red');
```

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:black;
  float:left;
}
.red{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a b c"></div>
```

---

**Original**:

What about:

```
$('.a.b:not(.c)')
```

which is the same as

```
$('.a.b').not('.c')
```

but simplier.

Comment: You exclude only .c class while I wanted to exclude any other classes beside .a and .b for example, there may be an element having a,b,c,d classes and I want to exclude that too.

Comment: Not an elegant way to do it but it's an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jquery` `.not` selector.

**:updated:** this will select only elements which have classes `a` and `b`.

```js
$("[class='a b'], [class='b a']").css("background", "blue");
```

```css
.a.b{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.c{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="a b">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="a b c">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ty for quick response. You exclude only .c class while I wanted to exclude any other classes beside .a and .b

Comment: Ohh Okay, See the updated answer. This will work for you